# Duplicate key value error message on a database for a writing groups scenario

Tags: insert, primary-key, errors, ddl

I am trying to create a database as portrayed in the following diagram:

[image]

This is the SQL-DDL code I have written:

```
CREATE TABLE Publishers
(
    PublisherName      VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,
    PublisherAddress   VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,
    PublisherPhone     VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,
    PublisherEmail     VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT pk_Publishers PRIMARY KEY (PublisherName)     
);

CREATE TABLE WritingGroup
(
    GroupName    VARCHAR(15)     NOT NULL,
    HeadWriter   VARCHAR(15)     NOT NULL,
    YearFormed   CHAR(4),  
    Subject      VARCHAR(15)     NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT pk_WritingGroup PRIMARY KEY (GroupName)
);

CREATE TABLE Books
(
    GroupName        VARCHAR(15)     NOT NULL,
    BookTitle        VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,
    PublisherName    VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,
    YearPublished    CHAR(4)         NOT NULL,  
    NumberPages      INTEGER         NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT pk_Books               PRIMARY KEY (GroupName,BookTitle),
    CONSTRAINT books_pub_fk1          FOREIGN KEY (PublisherName) REFERENCES Publishers (PublisherName),
    CONSTRAINT WritingGroups_Books_fk FOREIGN KEY (GroupName) REFERENCES WritingGroup(GroupName)
);


INSERT INTO publishers VALUES('P01','12345 h st ','+1 215 837 0825','e1@gmail.com');
INSERT INTO publishers VALUES('P02','6789 s st ','+1 215 967 9719','e2@gmail.com');

INSERT INTO books VALUES('GroupName1','title 1 ','P1','1994',50);

SELECT * FROM books
```

However when running the query I get the following error message:

> `[Exception, Error code 30,000, SQLState 23505] The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'PK_PUBLISHERS' defined on 'PUBLISHERS'.` 
>       `Line 38, column 1`

Can anybody see where the mistake is? This is my first time writing a database and I really dont see where I am going wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the books insert

```
INSERT INTO books VALUES('GroupName1','title 1 ','P1','1994',50);
```

You have a foreign key constraint, `books_pub_fk1`, referencing publishers, but you don't have a publisher P1, it is P01.

This is for referential integrity.

You will also have the same problem once this is fixed with `WritingGroups_Books_fk` as you don't have a group record in `WritingGroup` named `GroupName1`